# Unable to install ESLINT in vscode through npm because of following errors.How to resolve?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

command I am using for installation is "npm install @babel/eslint-parser --save-dev" also "sudo npm init @eslint/config".

ERROR that I am getting is below:

```
import { initializeConfig } from "../lib/init/config-initializer.js";
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)   
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)  
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)  
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)  
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)  
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)   
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)   
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong node version.  Per the npm eslint documentation:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint

Installation and Usage
Prerequisites: Node.js (^12.22.0, ^14.17.0, or >=16.0.0) built with SSL support. (If you are using an official Node.js distribution, SSL is always built in.)

You can check your node version by:

```
nvm list
```

And/Or you can check you version by:

```
node -v
```

Then you can run one of the correct node versions above by using for example:

```
nvm install v12.22.0
```

Then you can rerun your command for installing eslint:

```
npm init @eslint/config
```